# Node.js wait("await") for SQL database query before proceeding

Tags: sql, node.js, async-await

I have spent a lot of time reading up on this but I simply don't get how to solve it.

I have an application that uses a token that is stored in a SQL database. I need that token before the application can proceed.

I'm trying to solve it with "await" but it doesn't work. The SQL query result is still retrieved "too late".

```
const pool = mysql.createPool({
    user        : 'xxxx', // e.g. 'my-db-user'
    password    : "xxxx", // e.g. 'my-db-password'
    database    : "xxxx", // e.g. 'my-database'
    // If connecting via localhost, specify the ip
    host        : "xxxx"
    // If connecting via unix domain socket, specify the path
    //socketPath  : `/cloudsql/xxxx`,
});   

const isAuthorized = async (userId) => {
    
      let  query = "SELECT * FROM auth WHERE id = 2";
    
      
      await pool.query(query, (error,results) => {
        if (!results[0]) {
           console.log("No results");
           return
          } else {
            tokenyay=results[0].refreshtoken;
            console.log("results: "+results[0].refreshtoken);
            return results[0].refreshtoken;
            
          }
        });
      
    
      await console.log("tokenyay: "+tokenyay);
      
      if (tokenyay != null && tokenyay != '') {
      refreshTokenStore[userId] = tokenyay;
      }
    
      console.log(userId);
      console.log(refreshTokenStore[userId] ? true : false);
    
      return refreshTokenStore[userId] ? true : false;
    };
```

Comment: What is `pool`?

Comment: `pool.query` has a callback, so its type won't be a promise and your `await` will have no effect. You may consider converting it to a Promise using `util.promisify`, or manually creating a `new Promise` that resolves within the callback.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know what your `pool` is, but judging from the callback, we can see that `pool.query()` method is not `await`-able.

You can manually create a `Promise` for it, though, which is `await`-able, for example

```
await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.query(query, (error, results) => {
        if (error) reject(error);

        if (!results[0]) {
            console.log("No results");
            resolve(); // give `undefined` to the `await...` and make it stop waiting
            return;
        } else {
            tokenyay = results[0].refreshtoken;
            console.log("results: " + results[0].refreshtoken);
            resolve(results[0].refreshtoken);
        }

    })
});
```

---

**Edit:**

However, since the result of `await` is obtained from the value passed to the `resolve`, we don't need to assign `tokenyay` inside of the callback.
We can use `tokenyay = await...` instead.

```
tokenyay = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    pool.query(query, (error, results) => {
        if (error) reject(error);

        if (!results[0]) {
            console.log("No results");
            resolve(); // give `undefined` to the `await...` and make it stop waiting
            return;
        } else {
            console.log("results: " + results[0].refreshtoken);
            resolve(results[0].refreshtoken);
        }

    })
});
```

Comment: This works, thank you!

I have added the "pool" code to the question.

Comment: The assignment to `tokenyay` within the promise body is unnecessary and should be removed. The promise's resolved value is what you want to grab, so better to just `tokenyay = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {...` rather than to leak side-effects from within the promise.

Comment: @spender I agree it's better